# how to check record occurrence in a mysql table row by row

Tags: mysql

I have the following table:

[image]

I need to fill the `occurance` column like so:

[image]

I hope this can be done using `COUNT()` within a for loop or using a MySql row number simulation.

Comment: filling it while inserting will be much simpler, if that is an option

Answer (score 0):

Use inner join :

```
SELECT a.name, sum(1) FROM user a
inner join user b on a.id >= b.id and a.name=b.name
group by a.id
order by a.id
```

Result :

```
# name, sum(1)
'chamath', '1'
'chamath', '2'
'chanaka', '1'
'chanaka', '2'
'chanaka', '3'
'nuwan', '1'
'silva', '1'
```